# sklearn - ModuleNotFound despite is installing successfully

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, openai-api

I'm importing `get_embedding` from `openai.embeddings_utils`.

I received a `ModuleNotFound` error and, after installing

1. `matplotlib`
2. `plotly`
3. `scipy`

I got another saying that `sklearn` wasn't found.  I've installed that, apparently successfully:

```
Successfully built sklearn
Installing collected packages: sklearn
Successfully installed sklearn-0.0.post5
```

When I run the code though:

```py
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding

df['embedding'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:
                                   get_embedding(x, engine='text-embedding-ada-002'))
```

I still get the exception:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`

I'm *very* new to Python and Pip, is there some magic I need to do for this particular package?

Comment: You installed the wrong package, see https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/. You want to install `scikit-learn`, which is the _distribution package_ that includes the _import package_ `sklearn`.

Comment: @Brian61354270 is there an authorities place to find out what parent package one should use?  Like a "Pip Central" or something?

Comment: "Pip central" would be https://pypi.org/. As for what package name to use, check the documentation of the package you're trying to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try installing the package using:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```